# asp.net membership change password without knowing old one

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forgot-password, change-password

Evaluting the method signature, it is required to know old password while changing it.

```
membershipUser.ChangePassword(userWrapper.OldPassword, userWrapper.Password)
```

Is there any way to change password without knowing old one.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
 string username = "username";
 string password = "newpassword";
 MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);
 mu.ChangePassword(mu.ResetPassword(), password);
```

Comment: Note that `enablePasswordReset` option must be enabled in web.config membership provider configuration

Comment: Why can't you just use mu.GetPassword(); instead of mu.ResetPassword(); ?

Comment: @RMiranda you could use GetPassword but only if you're storing encrypted passwords in the database when you should be hashing them: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/

Comment: ResetPassword() returns new password. But first parameter of ChangePassword() represents old password. I don't understand. How to exactly works ResetPassword() method?

Answer (score 24):

The other answers here are correct, but can leave the password in an unknown state.

`ChangePassword` will throw exceptions if the password doesn't meet the requirements laid out in Web.Config (minimum length, etc.). But it only fails after `ResetPassword` has been called, so the password will not be known to the original user or to the person who's tried to change it. Check for complexity requirements before changing the password to avoid this:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(userName, false);

if ((newPassword.Length >= Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength) &&
    (newPassword.ToCharArray().Count(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) >=
         Membership.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters) &&
    ((Membership.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression.Length == 0) ||
         Regex.IsMatch(newPassword, Membership.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression))) {

    user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(), newPassword);
} else {
    // Tell user new password isn't strong enough
}
```

Comment: Even today that is a valid and insightful comment (for legacy code that I'm working on). Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

You need to reset the user's password before changing it, and pass in the generated password to `ChangePassword`.

```
string randompassword = membershipUser.ResetPassword();
membershipUser.ChangePassword(randompassword , userWrapper.Password)
```

or inline:

```
membershipUser.ChangePassword(membershipUser.ResetPassword(), userWrapper.Password)
```

Comment: Why can't you just use membershipUser.GetPassword(); instead of membershipUser.ResetPassword(); ?

Comment: @RMiranda - because passwords should never be stored in a retrievable way. They should be hashed instead. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x0c6sfa(v=vs.110).aspx and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification

Comment: ResetPassword() returns new password. But first parameter of ChangePassword() represents old password. I don't understand. How to exactly works ResetPassword() method?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use SimpleMembershipProvider it's easier:

```
var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken("LoginOfUserToChange");
WebSecurity.ResetPassword(token, "YourNewPassword");
```

Answer (score 4):

Please note, all these mentioned solutions will only work if the `RequiresQuestionAndAnswer` property is set to false in Membership system configuration. If `RequiresQuestionAndAnswer` is true then the ResetPassword method needs to be passed the security answer, otherwise it will throw an exception.

In case you need `RequiresQuestionAndAnswer` set to true, you can use this [workaround](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/admin/recovering-and-changing-passwords-vb)

Answer (score 2):

This code mentioned on posts above is working:

```
string username = "username";
string password = "newpassword";
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);
mu.ChangePassword(mu.ResetPassword(), password);
```

But you have to set requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" in web.config in membership provider tag. If it is true, resetpassword method  generate an error "Value can not be null".
In this case you must supply question answer as parameter to ResetPassword.

Answer (score 1):

Use the password you want to set from textbox in place of 123456.

```
 MembershipUser user;     
 user = Membership.GetUser(userName,false);
 user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(),"123456");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rob Church is right:

> The other answers here are correct but can leave the password in an
>   unknown state.

However, instead of his solution to do the validation by hand, I would try to change the password using the ResetPassword from token method and catch and show the error:

```
var user = UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
string token = UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
var result = UserManager.ResetPassword(user.Id, token, model.Password);
if (!result.Succeeded){
    // show error
}
```

Comment: this topic here is to use old Membership. But your code is from new Asp.Net Identity. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string username = "UserName";
string userpassword = "NewPassword";
string resetpassword;
    
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username, false);

if (mu == null){
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid Username!')</script>"); 
}

else{
    resetpassword = mu.ResetPassword(username);
    if (resetpassword != null){
         if (mu.ChangePassword(resetpassword, userpassword)){
             Response.Write("<script>alert('Password changed successfully!')</script>"); 
         }
    }
    else{
           Response.Write("<script>alert('Oh some error occurred!')</script>"); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string username = "UserName";
 string userpassword = "NewPassword";   
 MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username, false);
 mu.ChangePassword(mu.ResetPassword(username), userpassword);
```

Comment: Was this meant as an edit to your other answer?  Use the edit link underneath the post and delete this one.